# ASP.Net & jQuery - closing a popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, shadowbox, clientscriptmanager

I want to close a ShadowBox popup when the user clicks a button. The popup is showing a separate page in an Iframe.
This works fine with a clients-side event on the Cancel button control, e.g.

```
OnClientClick="javascript:parent.Shadowbox.close();"
```

The Ok button, however, has a server-side event, because data needs to be saved. When I define both an OnClick and the OnClientClick handler from above, the IFrame is closed and the server-side event handler never fires.

I tried to remove the OnClientClick event handler from the markup and to use the ClientScriptManager to accomplish this, as in

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
  "Close", "parent.Shadowbox.close();", true);
```

Apparently because the buttons are in an UpdatePanel, the script does not get registered, and it does not appear in the Reponse stream. The IPanel stays open.

How can I do this?

Comment: how did u solve this problem?? can u past the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the MS AJAX controls, you need to register your scripts with the `ScriptManager`, not `ClientScript`.

Comment: You mean like this:

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
                "CloseScript", "window.close();", true);

Makes no difference.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm interested now in why your original setup was preventing a postback.  OnClientClick shouldn't prevent the postback if your javascript wasn't returning false....

Comment: I wrote a new method that explicitly returns true, still no postback.

Comment: Injecting the script with the Scriptmanager is working. Not sure what was going on.